# Tomcat mssql and mysql connection pooling

Tags: mysql, sql-server, tomcat7, database-connection, connection-pooling

Case : I have two tomcats in a cluster running my Web application.  Both tomcats retrieve data from my MS SQL server and mysql database, do some process on the data and respond to requests. 
The data in the mysql dB is quite simple. As simple as the HR schema itself. The data is fetched from this dB in an average of 3-4ms
The data in the mssql dB however, is quite complex and I have stored procedures which internally run about 5-10 queries and respond. The time taken for this averages to about 6000ms.

Each of my tomcats have jdbc connection pooling setup for both these data sources. And they have been set the same for both my sql and mssql dB connections. 
The configuration is:

maxActive 100
maxIdle 30
maxWait 10000
minIdle 5
initialSize 5

I get stellar results with this configuration for my queries to mysql. But i am seeing issues when the load on the server increases, the connection to the MS sql server is received about 5000-10000ms after I request for a connection. Post which I execute the stored procedures which has take about 5000-6000ms.

I wasn't the one who setup all the servers and the poolsizes. But i am pretty sure the configuration shouldn't be the same for these two database connections.

I have checked all around but I couldn't find any direct relationship for the query execution time and connection pool settings.

If anyone out there has some suggestions about this, that would help a lot.

Comment: If the SQL server takes 6s to respond, and you get 100 concurrent requests, then the 101st will have to wait for one of the existing connections to become free - at most 6s, and possibly exactly 6s. Now, if you have 100 more concurrent requests, each has to wait 6s for a connection + 6s more for data, 12s. What then happens when we have 100 more concurrent requests? See the problem? Sadly, given the slowness of the queries, and the inherent multithreaded nature of web servers, it is not a problem that can be solved. You will have to speed up your SQL if you want high levels of concurrency...

Comment: Have you tried caching? Or possibly have 100 worker threads that deal with the SQL, and do that asynchronously in the background - must the SQL complete before the request is returned?

Comment: I am thinking of caching. That will be a long term solution. I want to fix this temporarily while my caching solution is being designed. I am thinking of caching the data in redis or postgre. But it will take some time for me design the caching system. So I need to tune or tweak my connection settings right now as in for the next 3 months

Comment: See above. You cannot. You have a resource constraint, and it's not the connection pool. No amount of tweaking will magically get you those 6 seconds back.

Comment: I don't want the 6 second the query takes.. I want the 5-10 seconds that my server waits to get the connection from the pool

Comment: Can't you see that those are one and the same? If you assign more connections, you'll just the the bottleneck later but the bottleneck is the same; once the pileup begins it will grind the whole lot to a stop.

Comment: The average time I posted for the execution of the stored procedure is 6s. Thats majorly because there are three peaks of 'one hour' during the day where I get almost 50% of the total hits to my server.

Comment: If increasing the connection pools initial size helps me get through that time, I would have solved half my issue. I have started working on the queries in the Stored procedures for better performance.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the fact about both the wait time for connection and the query execution time are the same :) that totally skipped my mind.